# tooltip-class is not working with ui-bootstrap-tpls.0.11.0

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was trying to customize tooltip style with `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-class="customClass" tooltip="Test tooltip"></i>
```

And in CSS file:

```
.customClass .tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

But the tooltip's width never changed, it has the default 200px from `bootstrap.css`.

I also tried to use the following code:

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" tooltip="Test tooltip" tooltip-class="customClass" tooltip-append-to-body="true"> </i>
```

with CSS:

```
.tooltip.customClass .tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

and it doesn't work either.

I'm using `ui-bootstrap-tpls.0.11.0`, and wonder if this is because that the old version ui-bootstrap doesn't support tooltip-class. If that is the case, is there anyway I can add style for tooltip?

Comment: what actually your are trying to customize?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this maybe it will help but the ui version is not a problem.

http://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/pNOaYX

```
.tooltip-inner {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it still not working. I wonder if this is because of the older version of ui-bootstrap-tpls.0.11.0. tooltip-class is not supported?

Comment: Thanks for the sample. However, when using tooltip-append-to-body="true", your example will apply the style to all the tooltip, which is not my purpose. I would like to apply this style only to some of the tooltip.

Comment: that is fine just change the class name. I had to insert any code to post the codepen link. You need to use a min-width and not max-width as used.